# Atiyah Sequence and Connections on a Principal Bundle

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, connections, principal-bundles

Let $G$ be a Lie group and $\pi:E_G\rightarrow M $ be a principal $G$-bundle.

I have seen in many places that a connection on $(E_G,M,G)$ is a splitting of the Atiyah sequence

$$ 0\rightarrow \text{ad}(E_G)\rightarrow \text{At}(E_G)\rightarrow T M\rightarrow 0$$

where $\text{ad}(E_G)$ is the adjoint vector bundle for $E_G$ and $\text{At}(E_G)$ is the Atiyah bundle for $E_G$.

Reference given for this is Atiyah's [paper](http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1957-085-01/S0002-9947-1957-0086359-5/S0002-9947-1957-0086359-5.pdf). This paper is slightly difficult to read.

Can some one give an outline of this construction or point out some exposition where this is written in detail.

Comment: Chen-Stiénon-Xu ([2016](//ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=3439229)) is quite good and further recommends Kapranov ([1999](//ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1671737)). Both are on arXiv. There is also Biswas-Raghavendra ([2008](//ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2413755); [pdf](//www.insa.nic.in/writereaddata/UpLoadedFiles/IJPAM/20014c96_3.pdf)).

Comment: @FrancoisZiegler sir, thank you for references. I will see and tell which I found it useful for my purpose... thank you...

Comment: Can some one tell me what is the reason for downvote?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First note that the adjoint bundle $ad(E_G)$ can be canonically identified with the vertical tangent bundle $V E_G / G$: send the pair $(p, \xi)$ consisting of a point $p \in E_G$ and a Lie algebra element $\xi$ to the value $p \cdot \xi$ at $p$ of the fundamental vector field generated by $\xi$. Moreover, the Atiyah bundle $At(E_G)$ is just a fancy way of writing $T E_G / G$.

Thus, a splitting of the Atiyah sequence is nothing else than a diffeomorphism of $T E_G / G$ with the direct sum $V E_G /G \oplus T M$ (taken over $M$). In this way, you recover the definition of a connection as a complement to $V E_G$. The horizontal bundle is the image of $TM$ under the above isomorphism $V E_G \oplus T M \to T E_G / G$. Alternatively, you can view a splitting as a projection onto $V E_G$ or as a $G$-equivariant lift $TM \to TE_G$. These equivalent viewpoints give you the definition of a connection as a connection $1$-form and as a horizontal lift operator, respectively. I've expanded a bit on the different but equivalent viewpoints [in an answer to a different question](https://mathoverflow.net/a/245576/17047).

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer...if $ad(E_G)$ is identified with vertical tangent bundle $VE_G$ and Atiyah bundle $At(E_G)$ is fancy way of writing the quotient $TE_G/G$ then, I think I understand what this Atiyah sequence has to do with connection.. I will try to write down how “$At(E_G)$ is fancy way of writing the quotient $TE_G/G$” thanks thanks...

Comment: Can you give some reference  to read about this Atiyah sequence in more detail?

Comment: You mean $\frac{TE_G}{G}\cong VE_G\oplus TM$ and not $TE_G \cong VE_G\oplus TM$. right? Am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, thanks for pointing this out. Changed my answer accordingly.

Comment: Oh.. Ok..  Thanks :)

Comment: The horizontal bundle is the image of $TM$ under the isomorphism $VP\oplus TM \cong (TP)/G$ is a sub bundle of the bunlde $TP/G$ and not $TP$ which is  the usual place where horizontal bundle is located at.. I am trying to figure out what I am missing... You need not respond if you are busy.. This is note for my self too..

Comment: What do you think would be motivation for defining connection in this fashion...?

Answer (score 2):

See the paper [The Atiyah bundle and connections on a principal bundle](https://www.ias.ac.in/article/fulltext/pmsc/120/03/0299-0316) by Indranil Biswas.

Let $p:E_G\rightarrow M$ be a principal $G$-bundle. Michael Atiyah in his [paper](https://www.ias.ac.in/article/fulltext/pmsc/120/03/0299-0316) uses a exact sequence of vector bundles over $M$, namely $$0\rightarrow \text{ad}(E_G)\rightarrow \text{At}(E_G)\rightarrow TM\rightarrow 0$$
to define a connection on the principal bundle as a section of above exact sequence. Here,

- $\text{ad}(E_G):(E_G\times\mathfrak{g})/G\rightarrow M$ is the adjoint bundle associated to the principal $G$-bundle $E_G\rightarrow M$ with adjoint action of $G$ on $P$.
- $\text{At}(E_G):TE_G/G\rightarrow M$ is the Atiyah bundle. Consider the tangent bundle $TE_G\rightarrow E_G$. Action of $G$ on $E_G$ induce an acion of $G$ on $TE_G$ as well. This map $TE_G\rightarrow E_G$ is $G$-equivariant, giving a vector bundle $TE_G/G\rightarrow E_G/G$. As $E_G/G\cong M$, this gives vector bundle $TE_G/G\rightarrow M$, a vector bundle over $M$.

The map $E_G\times \mathfrak{g}\rightarrow TE_G$ given by $(p,A)\rightarrow (\delta_p)_{*,e}(A)$ where $\delta_p:G\rightarrow E_G$ is given by $g\mapsto pg$. Even this map $E_G\times \mathfrak{g}\rightarrow TE_G$ is **$G$-equivariant**, giving $(E_G\times \mathfrak{g})/G\rightarrow TE_G/G$. This map of manifolds is good enough to give a morphsim $\text{ad}(E_G)\rightarrow \text{At}(E_G)$
 of vector budnles over $M$.  The map $P\rightarrow M$ gives $TP\rightarrow TM$. This map is **$G$-invarinat**, giving $TP/G\rightarrow TM$. Again, this map is good enough to give a morphism $\text{At}(P)\rightarrow TM$ of vector bundles over $M$.

Combining above morphisms of vector bundles over $M$, this gives an exact sequence of vector bundles
$$0\rightarrow \text{ad}(P)\rightarrow \text{At}(P)\rightarrow TM\rightarrow 0.$$

Then, author says, a connection is splitting of above exact sequence.

There are two ways (that I know) to think about splitting. One way is to talk about the direct sum $\text{At}(E_G)\cong \text{ad}(E_G)\oplus TM$ and the second is a section $s:TM\rightarrow \text{At}(E_G)$.

To  relate to the notion of connection that we already know (as a distribution $\mathcal{H}\subset TE_G$) satisfying some properties, it is useful to think of splitting as a section $s:TM\rightarrow \text{At}(E_G)$. The map $p:E_G\rightarrow M$ pullback the bundle $\text{At}(E_G)\rightarrow M$ to give $p^*(\text{At}(E_G))\rightarrow E_G$ and pullback the bundle $TM\rightarrow M$ to give $p^*TM\rightarrow E_G$. Further, the map $s:TM\rightarrow \text{At}(E_G)$ is pullback to give $D:p^*TM\rightarrow p^*(\text{At}(E_G))$.

In page number [$301$](https://www.ias.ac.in/article/fulltext/pmsc/120/03/0299-0316) (equation $2.7$), they defines a morphism of vector bundles $\mu:p^*(\text{At}(E_G))\rightarrow TE_G $ and observes  that this is an isomorphism of vector bundles.

Consider the composition $p^*TM\xrightarrow{D} p^*(\text{At}(E_G))\xrightarrow{\mu} TE_G$.

Image of this map, i.e., $\mathcal{H}(D):=(\mu\circ D)(p^*TM)\subset TE_G$ is a sub bundle. This plays the role of Horizantal sub bundle when defining connection in the sense of Kobayashi and Nomizu.

This is how we relate the two notions of connection on a principal $G$-bundle $E_G\rightarrow M$, one as a splitting of the Atiyah sequence of vector bundles and the other as a distribution of $TE_G$ satisfying some properties.

---

Another way I learned from Ralph Cohen's [notes](http://math.stanford.edu/~ralph/fiber.pdf) (Page number $35$). He does not say in this form, I am interpreting. One can pullback the 
 exact sequence $$0\rightarrow \text{ad}(E_G)\rightarrow \text{At}(E_G)\rightarrow TM\rightarrow 0 $$ 
of **vector bundles over $M$** along the map $p:E_G\rightarrow M$ to get the exact sequence 
$$0\rightarrow p^*(\text{ad}(E_G))\rightarrow p^*(\text{At}(E_G))\rightarrow p^*(TM)\rightarrow 0 $$
of **vector bundles over $P$**. Ralph Cohen defines a connection on $p:E_G\rightarrow M$ to be a $G$-equivariant splitting of the  above exact sequence of vector bundles. As mentioned above, there is an isomrophism of vector bundles 
$p^*(\text{At}(E_G))\cong TE_G$, that gives following sequence  $$0\rightarrow p^*(\text{ad}(E_G))\rightarrow TE_G\rightarrow p^*(TM)\rightarrow 0 $$
of vector bundles over $P$. A section of above sequence $s:p^*(TM)\rightarrow TE_G$ gives a sub bundle $\mathcal{H}:=s(p^*(TM))\subset TE_G$, giving a distribution. This is compatible with the structure of prinipal bundle, giving a connection in the sense of distribution $\mathcal{H}\subseteq TE_G$.

Comment: In the paper he writes that the Atiyah bundle has rank = dim$(g+ \mathbb R^d)$. Can you tell me what is the vector space lying over each $m$ in $M$ explicitly?

Comment: I do not think I understand your question correctly.. I will give a try... The Atiyah bundle is the quotient bundle $(TP)/G\rightarrow M$.. For each $m\in M$, the fibre is $$\{[(p,v]\in (TP)/G : \pi(p)=m\}$$ Are you asking this or you want to know anything else? @angry_math_person

Comment: So choosing a particular point $p$ in the fibre of $m$ and giving a tangent vector at that point determines the tangent vectors at all other points? That is your equivalence relation right? The reason you put a square bracket around $(p,v)$?

Comment: "a particular point $p$ in the fibre of $m$ and giving a tangent vector at that point determines the tangent vectors at all other points?".. You can take a point $p\in P$ with $\pi(p)=m$, consider the orbit $\{p g : g\in G\}$which is precisely the fiber of $m$... Or, if you want to see in a different language, you can just collect all elements in fiber of $m$, take their tangent spaces $\{T_pP: p\in \pi^{-1}(m)\}$, and identify two elements $v\in T_pP$, $v'\in T_{p'}P$ if there is a $g$ which connects them.. To remind that we are identifying, we put a bracket $[(p,v)]$.. @angry_math_person

Comment: Sorry to keep on dragging, but I'm failing to see why the rank of the fibre is dim$(\mathbb R^d + g)$. The fibre of Atiyah bundle seems to be specified by the tangent space at any point on the fibre of the original bundle. Now the original bundle has fibres diffeomorphic to $G$ and hence tangent space is isomorphic to $g$. But I don't see how the extra $d$ dimensions are accounted for?

Comment: @angry_math_person Its alright, not a problem.. If you have access to the book "Lie groupoids and Lie algebroids in differential geometry" by Mackenzie, please see the appendix.. it mention the Atiyah sequence, that is where I learned it... If you don't have access to the book, you can read section 2.4 in my thesis https://arxiv.org/abs/2112.13472 if you are still not convinced, we can discuss further..

Comment: I'll try to read the materials you suggested. But for the time being can you answer this question. If i understand correctly the fibre of Atiyah bundle over each point of base space is the vector space of invariant vector fields on the fibre of the starting principal bundle. Now Indranil Biswas in his paper writes that this is supposed to have rank = $dim(\mathbb R^d + g)$. I can't see why that is the rank. Can you tell me why?

Comment: @angry_math_person Ok.. What do you think of the relation between dimension of $P$ and dimension of $M\times G$? What do we know about the relation between dimension of $P$ and rank of the tangent bundle $TP\rightarrow P$?

Comment: Ahh! Both of them are equal to dim($M \times G$). And hence equal to dim($\mathbb R^d + g$). Thank you.

Comment: @angry_math_person you are welcome.. If it is clear to you, I am happy, but, I want to highlight that, the morphisms of vector bundles (TP--->P)---> ((TP)/G---->M) induce isomorphism of fibers.. for each $p\in P$, this morphism of vector bundles restrict to give isomorphism between tangent space of $p\in P$ and the fiber of $\pi(p)=m$..

Answer (score 1):

This is from another reference. So, adding as a different answer.

Appendix A "On principal bundles and Atiyah sequences" in the book [Lie groupoids and Lie algebroids in differential geometry](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/lie-groupoids-and-lie-algebroids-in-differential-geometry/6B8B1D00E8B7672ABA80A0C950FD4979) by Kirill Mackenzie discuss Atiyah sequence approach of connection on Principal bundles.

AMS review of the book by Antonio Kumpera
 can be found [here](https://www.ams.org/journals/bull/1988-19-01/S0273-0979-1988-15675-3/S0273-0979-1988-15675-3.pdf)

Comment: This is already very standard book and does not need my appreciation but I would like to say this is very well written (I only saw appendix)...

Comment: I will be more than happy to discuss about the appendix (any thing else) from the book..